# Filtering out lines in TXT and inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to search for a string in a line in a txt file, the line that contains the string which I am searching for has to be inserted into my database.

The php while loops through all lines an like I said, I am trying to insert the lines it finds into my Database.

Now the problem is, that if I run this code, it inserts all of the txt file in my database, I can't figure out why.

```
$search = $_GET["search"]; 
$logfile = $_GET['logfile'];
// Read from file 
$file = fopen($logfile, "r");
?> 
<head> <title>Searching: <?php echo $search ?></title> </head> 
<?php
while( ($line =  fgets($file) )!= false)
{
if(stristr($line,$search))
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
if(stristr($line,$search))
$sql = "INSERT INTO `ingamebanlist` (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('$line', '$timestamp')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
// case insensitive
echo "<font face='Arial'> $line </font><hr>";
}
fclose($file);
```

Please ask any questions if it is unclear

Comment: could you provide us sample of your file content and search string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely because you didn't structure your code. The main culprit are checks like this:

```
if(stristr($line,$search))
$servername = "localhost";
```

The `if` just masks the following line. You ought to enclose code blocks in `{` and `}` to conditionally run them only on matches. You're sort of doing the same thing for crafting the `$sql=` query. Albeit that should just double previous lines on insertion.

And you really ought to move the mysqli connection code out of the loop. Do that once beforehand.

Btw, a more compact way of reading and filtering the input would be:

```
$f = new SplFileObject("logfile.txt", "r");
$f = new RegexIterator($f, "/" . preg_quote($search, "/") . "/i");
foreach ($f as $line) {
    db::insert(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$array = file($filename)` reads the file given in `$filename` in an array (one per line), you may then iterate the array using i.e. `foreach()` and search in each line. if your search string match in that line, insert into database...

```
$lines = file($logfile);
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
foreach($lines as $line) {
    if(stristr($line,$search))
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `ingamebanlist` (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('$line', '$timestamp')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
    // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace your loop with this one:

```
while( ($line =  fgets($file) )!= false)
{
    if(stristr($line,$search)) {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "pass";
        $dbname = "db";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `ingamebanlist` (Ban, Timestamp) VALUES ('$line', '$timestamp')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {                                                                                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;                                                                              }                                                                               $conn->close();
            echo "<font face='Arial'> $line </font><hr>";
        }
    }
}
fclose($file);
```